# Customizing the Twitter Bootstrap default grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less, responsive-design

I'm trying to change the number of columns in the default Bootstrap grid from 12 to 8. According to the [Bootstrap docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html), this involves changing the `@gridColumns` variable and then customizing the grids in responsive.less.

I've tried to edit the grids in responsive.less (and the files it imports), but I can't get it right. What specific values do I need to change the grid from 12 columns to 8?

Comment: Have you [recompiled the CSS](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/less.html#compiling) (or are you using less.js to compile at runtime)?

Comment: Yes. I'm using lessc to compile the CSS.

Comment: Open up a DOM viewer and see what your column widths are.  Make sure it's actually using the correct files.  If it is, make sure you also edit the column gutters.

Comment: @JosephMornin You can customize the bootstrap grids right on the documentation page over at the [Customize](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/download.html) section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open up variables.less it contains all of the variables you need to change near the bottom:

```
@gridColumns:             16;
@gridColumnWidth:         45px;
@gridGutterWidth:         16px;
```

Make sure you are loading the less and not the css

Comment: Turns out this was a browser caching issue. Editing the variables works.